# After i click on collapse button i want to add top + 100 and second click should be top - 100

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image][image: this is image]this is jQuery i tried to used toggle also but it is not working properly

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".sidebar ul li").click(function () {
                $(this).siblings().find(':nth-child(1)').css("display", "none");
                $(this).addClass('margin').siblings().removeClass('margin');
                $(this).find(':nth-child(1)').css("display", "block");
            });


            $(".navbar-toggler-icon").click(function () {
                    $("#sidebar ul li").find(':nth-child(1)').css("top", "+=100px")
                }

            );
        })
    </script>
```

this is html css part where is want to add top+100 and subtract top-100 after clicking collapse button this is not working i tried to use toggle also but it is displaying both the img element

```
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="" alt="" width="80"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <form class="ml-auto">
                    <div class="searchbar">
                        <input type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button type="submit"><img src="images/search.svg" alt="" width="15"></button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-link mr-4">Home</li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><img src="" alt=""> <img style="border-radius: 50%" src="" alt=""> Contact US
                        <img src="images/down.svg" alt=""></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">

            <li class="nav-link">Home<img class="select_line"
                    style="display:none; position: absolute; left: 160px; top: 140px;" src="images/gear.svg"></li>
            <li class="nav-link">Activity<img class="select_line"
                    style="display:none; position: absolute; left: 160px; top: 190px;" src="images/gear.svg"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Add a classes on toggle. And inside these classes define the style

Answer (score 1):

You can also use .toggleClass from jQuery. Since you have not added your entire HTML, below I have added an example. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#toggle").click(function () {
                    $("#sidebar ul").toggleClass("toggleTop")
                }

            );
        })
```

```css
.toggleTop{
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">
Toggle
</button>

<div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto toggleTop">

            <li class="nav-link">Home<img class="select_line"
                    style="display:none; position: absolute; left: 160px; top: 140px;" src="images/gear.svg"></li>
            <li class="nav-link">Activity<img class="select_line"
                    style="display:none; position: absolute; left: 160px; top: 190px;" src="images/gear.svg"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: this is also not working as i had already defined top 140px so this is working perfectly but after clicking collapse i have to add top 100px so, that it can be aligned perfectly that i.e. 140px + 100px = 240px

Answer (score 0):

You can use `animate()`. It will provide you with animation which would definitely seem cool.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sidebar ul li").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().find(':nth-child(1)').css("display", "none");
    $(this).addClass('margin').siblings().removeClass('margin');
    $(this).find(':nth-child(1)').css("display", "block");
  });

  var flag = true;


  $(".navbar-toggler-icon").click(function() {
      if (flag) {
        $("#sidebar ul li:first-child").animate({
          "margin-top": "+=100"
        });
      } else {
        $("#sidebar ul li:first-child").animate({
          "margin-top": "-=100"
        });
      }
      flag = !flag;
    }

  );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
  <button class="navbar-toggler-icon">Collapse</button>
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">

    <li class="nav-link">Home<img class="select_line" style="display:none; position: absolute; left: 160px; top: 140px;" src="images/gear.svg"></li>
    <li class="nav-link">Activity<img class="select_line" style="display:none; position: absolute; left: 160px; top: 190px;" src="images/gear.svg"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, this is  working but can you please help me like after clicking on button second time it is still adding the top +  100 but it should be top -100 so how to implement this condition

Comment: Please check again. On first click, it will add 100px to the `margin-top`, but on second click, it will remove the added margin.